# If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is measurable then so is $-E$

Tags: measure-theory

Given measurable $E$, if $-E := \{x: -x \in E\}$, how do I show $-E$ is measurable?

Comment: What is the definition of "measurable"?  Use that.  Depending on the exact definition in you textbook, this could be either very easy, or moderately easy.

Comment: For any set $A$, $m^{*}(A) = m^{*}(A \cap E) + m^{*} (A \cap E^{C})$.

Comment: Good start.  Can you show $m^*(A) = m^*(-A)$?  And relate $-(A \cap E)$ to $-A$ and $-E$?

Comment: I can prove the first part by the definition of outer measure, since the length of an interval is unchanged under translation. And $-(A \cap E) = \{x: -x \in A \cap E \} = \{x: -x \in A \} \cap \{x: -x \in E \} = -A \cap -E$.

Comment: My question is though, is it $-(A \cap E)$ that we're really interested in, or $-A \cap E$? Because $m^{*}(-A) = m^{*}(-A \cap E) + m^{*}(-A \cap E^{C})$.

I suppose then we could say $-A \cap E = -A \cap -(- E) = -(A \cap - E)$. So we then have:

$m^{*}(-A \cap E) + m^{*} (-A \cap E^{C}) = m^{*}(-(A \cap -E)) + m^{*}(-(A \cap (-E)^{C}))$.

We then note that this equals $m^{*}(A \cap -E) + m^{*} (A \cap (-E)^{C})$ looking at the intersections as separate subsets of $A$, yes?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The outer measure of $E$ is
$$
\lambda^{*}(E)=\inf\left\{ \sum_{k}\sup I_{k}-\inf I_{k}\colon(I_{k})_{k}\text{ is a sequence of open intervals covering }E\right\} .
$$
Let $(I_{k})_{k}$ be a sequence of open intervals.
Then $(-I_{k})_{k}$
is also a sequence of open intervals and
$$
\sum_{k}\sup I_{k}-\inf I_{k}=\sum_{k}\sup(-I_{k})-\inf(-I_{k}).
$$
What can you conclude from this?

GEdgar's comment (which I saw after finishing TeXing the above) is the same as my hint.

Answer (score 1):

It is the inverse image of the measurable map $x \mapsto -x$.

Comment: I think saying "measurable" taken by itself means: for a set Lebesgue measurable and for a function measurable from Lebesgue to Borel.  Then the question as stated is about measurability of $x \mapsto -x$ for Lebesgue to Lebesgue.  If so, you are merely restating the question!

Comment: I operate under the convention that $mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the usual measurable structure.

Comment: I think this answer is circular; it implicitly assumes the very statement that BMac wants to prove.

Comment: @Tom Price, The definition used by BMac is the Lebesgue measure, which is the completion of Borel measure. There is a theorem that tells you that a continuous function is (Borel, Lebesgue) measurable. So, this solution doesn't seem circular to me,  but maybe is using too many facts.

Comment: @JulianMejia The inverse image of a Lebesgue measurable set under  a continuous function need not be Lebesgue measurable.